# New Ubuntu user, wireless connection - firefox won't work

Tags: internet

I'm new to linux. Just installed Ubuntu 11.10. Setting up seemed to go ok. 
I seem to be able to connect to my wireless connection ( says "connection established") but fir fox says "Server not found when i try to connect to internet.

Please remember to keep it simple if you ask me to enter code into the terminal as I am new to this.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to askubuntu, and congratulations for diving into a decent computing environnment.

I suspect your wireless is connected, but you may have a DNS problem.

Try these 2 simple ping commands, in a console:

```
ping google.ca
```

Then:

```
ping 173.194.73.94
```

If the second ping does not resolve ( it should return 3 ping results by default), this would mean you HAVE an Internet connection, just no properly configured DNS resolver.

If that is the case, I suggest you configure your DNS [by following this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-configure-dns-nameserver-ip-address/).

Oh, if you need a DNS server to setup against you can use [google's public dns service](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

- If both pings do not resolve, it could be you are connected to your router but the router is not connected to Internet.
- If you want to rule out that firefox is the culprit, try installing chrome or even lynx:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lynx
  ```

Or..

```
   sudo apt-get install chrome
```

Then, in a console:

```
lynx google.com
```

If this brings you the beautiful google page (in text mode), Firefox is the culprit. I would surprised if this was the case. I am betting you have a (quite common) DNS configuration problem.

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. First ping returned "Unknown host google.ca" and the second returned "Network is unreachable"

Comment: Still having problems, please help...

Comment: Then,  you have no Internet connection my friend, your NIC card, was it detected at startup? See this page for some general help on network configuration: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html

Comment: sudo lshw -class network - paste the resultof thisin a pastebin and post the link here

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sWwHa9Vu

Comment: I think I got that right.. (Never used a paste bin before.) That link you sent was full of good info but just confused the hell out of me. Sorry.

Comment: Upvoted the question to (hopefully) push it back up the frontpage. I am not a 'wireless guru', but I am sure there will be help. This page should be even better to track down you wireless: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide.  When you fix the issue, if you have a chance to post what fixed the issue (as an answer if need be) so others with same problem can have a help page out there. Follow the steps on that above link. Should not be too difficult and you will learn a few wireless tips while at it. You can message me if you need help on *anything in there*.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will keep looking thru the documentation and see how I go. I'm sure it will be some simple setting but right now... I can't work it out.

Comment: Dave, don't give up friend, it is indeed probably a minor configuration issue. Have you checked the wireless troubleshooting guide? Don't hesitate to message me if you are stuck on a point.

Comment: @ stefgosselin Haven't given up yet, but don't have much hair left, and have bandaids on my forehead from bashing my head against the wall.... I have used the trouble shooting guide and confirmed my device and drivers are good. The next part of the guide loses me. My network manager seems to say "connection confirmed" but i noticed that my connection is "ad-hoc" and I can't get it to connect if i choose "infrastructure"... *big sigh* getting frustrated....

Comment: @Dave do not despair, you are on the right track.  You have gathered more than enough  info to slap down a quick summary with some of the output from those commands you  learned from that wireless troubleshooting page in a *new post*. I know at the beginning some people are put off when a hickup like this happens, but rest assured you will get help, and if your card was detected like you said it is very close to working. Point a link to *this post*, and for sure we will see more answers pour in.  This usually is actually not common, maybe a simple re-install would of done the trick too.

Comment: Thanks. Have lost count of the number of time I've reinstalled.

Comment: Will repost new thread shortly. Thanks for all your help....